# How can I know if the cyber-protection offered by my ISP is worth the extra cost?

Tags: isp, consumer-protection

My ISP offers a "cyber protection" service at an extra cost. They say it "identifies and blocks privacy attacks, credit-card scams, identity thefts and hacker attacks against computers connected to your home network", but do not say how they do this.

Is there a test I can make, in order to see if their cyber-protection is worth the extra cost, or maybe I should look for cyber-protection elsewhere?

Comment: I dont know enough to write a detailed answer but the "cyber protection" seems bullshit.

Comment: It's most likely just a way for your ISP to make money off of gullible people. But if you feel inquisitive, you can call your ISP and say you are interested in buying it, but you would like to know what it does for you and how it works.

Comment: If ***you*** don't know what it is, I'm not sure how we can tell you what it is or how effective it might be.

Comment: Please edit your question with details about what this is, and then we can figure out its effectiveness.

Answer (score 3):

My ISP (SFR, French one) also sell this option.

It basically consists of a "security app" for Windows/Mac OS X/iOS/Android that implements antivirus, anti-malware, browser analysis, etc...

It's more or less the equivalent of Avast, Kaspersky, etc...

Since I wouldn't "buy bread from a butcher", I didn't buy the "security app" from SFR.